# How to access to iteration variable in c:forEach with a scriptlet/expression?

Tags: jakarta-ee, foreach, jstl, java-ee-6

**var** is a static attribute to expose the current element (local to the body)

How to acces to var attribute through scriptlet/expression?

**Initialization code**

```
<% 
Employee e = new Employee();
e.setName("name");
e.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");
java.util.List<Employee> empList = new java.util.ArrayList();
empList.add(e);
request.setAttribute("empList", empList); %>
```

**forEach code 1** deferredExpression Error

```
<c:forEach var="emp" items="${employees}">
  <c:out value="${emp.name}"/><br><%=emp.getName()%> 
</c:forEach>
```

**NOR**

**forEach code 2** deferredExpression Error

```
<c:forEach var="emp" items="${empList}" varStatus="status">
  Emp email: <%= ((Employee)(pageContext.findAttribute("emp"))).getName() %>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: deferredExpression every time I change because of I had different versions of JSTL libraries, and now I only leave one jstl-1.2.jar [more info about JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info).

The JSTL documentation documentation says it clearly "Name of the exported scoped variable for the current item of the iteration. *This scoped variable has nested visibility*." and nested means from the start tag  until the end tag .

EL code

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="5" var="countvar">
Iteration number ${ countvar + 24 }
</c:forEach>
```

Alternative JSP scripting

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="5" var="countvar">
Iteration number
<%= ((Integer) (pageContext.findAttribute("cv")).intValue()+24 %>
</c:forEach>
```

Another c:forEach example with a collection

```
<% 
 Employee e = new Employee();
 e.setName("name");
 e.setEmail("abc@gmail.com");
 java.util.List<Employee> empList = new java.util.ArrayList();
 empList.add(e);
 request.setAttribute("empList", empList); 
%>

<c:forEach var="emp" items="${empList}" varStatus="status">
  Emp email: <%= ((Employee)(pageContext.findAttribute("emp"))).getName() %>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 3):

I use following general snippet:

```
<c:forEach items="<%= itemList %>" var="item">
    <%
        ItemClass item = (ItemClass)pageContext.getAttribute("item");
    %>
    <p>Value with scriptlet: <%= item.getValue() %></p>
    <p>Value with EL ${item.value}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Your case with EL:

```
<c:forEach var="emp" items="<%= empList %>" varStatus="status">
  ${emp.name} email: ${emp.email}
</c:forEach>
```

Your case with scriptlet:

```
<c:forEach var="emp" items="<%= empList %>" varStatus="status">
  <%
      Employee employee = (Employee)pageContext.getAttribute("emp");
  %>
  <%= employee.getName() %> email: <%= employee.getEmail() %>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<c:forEach var="emp" items="${empList}" varStatus="status">
  <c:out value="Emp email: ${emp.email}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: you are using expression language here, not scriptlet <%..%> or expressions <%=..%>